# Angular4 sharing data to child component

Tags: angular

I have a parent component that invokes an API and gets the data returned.
It has a loop like this:

```
<div *ngIf="campaign">
    <div *ngFor="let question of campaign.questions" bzQuestion></div>
</div>
```

You can see that I have another component called **bzQuestion** that repeats itself. I want to pass the data (question) to that component. I watched a video saying you can use **@Input()**, so I did this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IQuestion } from '../data/models/question.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'bz-question',
  templateUrl: './question.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./question.component.scss'],
  providers: [ ]
})
export class QuestionComponent {
  @Input() public question: IQuestion;
}
```

I tried to then add the question to the child component by doing this to the parent:

```
<div *ngIf="campaign">
    <div *ngFor="let question of campaign.questions" [question]="question" bzQuestion></div>
</div>
```

But the compiler moans saying:

> Can't bind to 'question' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: <bzQuestion *ngFor="let question of campaign.questions" [question]="question" ></bzQuestion>

Comment: The answer is in your error message, `question` is not a known prop of `div` but it is a known prop of `bzQuestion`

Comment: What about `<bz-question *ngFor="let question of campaign.questions" [question]="question"></bz-question>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do it in component, not div. Component selector is app-bzQuestion, or something like that, u can find that in .ts file of your component.

```
<div *ngIf="campaign">
    <app-bzQuestion *ngFor="let question of campaign.questions" [question]="question"></app-bzQuestion>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I do it will an attribute directive? `<a href="#" bzResize [multipler]="resizeMultipler">`